# Laravel 5.4 firstOrCreate or firstOrNew if unique is only id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, insert

I'am working on my small project and there is problem.
Learning Laravel is fun and write code the way Laravel team wants is fun to, but sometimes i feel like I'am to narrow minded to solve problems where they shouldn't be.

After reading documentation - for me in general firstOrCreate or firstOrNew functions are the same. So as i understand i can create one function to handle insert and update functions. 
So far so good.
But i have problem with inserting if 'bill_id' does't exist.

For example in my routs

```
Route::post('/bill/save/', 'BillsController@saveBill');
```

and in my BillsController

```
public function saveBill(Request $request)
{   

    $bill = Bills::firstOrNew(['id' => $request->bill_id]);
    $bill->client_id = $request->client_id;
    ...
    $bill->save();
    return redirect('admin/clients/'.$request->client_id);
}
```

what do i did in view is created a hidden field with name bill_id and getting that bill_id from db.

```
{!! Form::text('bill_id',$data['id'], ['hidden']) !!}
```

In view page where i create new bill - that bill_id input field still exist but with empty value.

```
{!! Form::text('bill_id','', ['hidden']) !!}
```

So because bill_id is empty i got error.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for > column 'id' at row 1

I believe that learning framework is good and sometimes is tricky to find right way to write good code and sometimes for me its becomes hackish way to do things. And only after some updates and hours learning i realize how is the the right way to write code. But this time i just cant find the way **how to pass empty bill_id and make controller to insert data in db and if bill_id exists its just updates table**.

And normal php if else statements i think is not ok in this case. There must be the correct whey to do that.

Using insert and update function everything works as it should do, but in firstOrCreate or firstOrNew functions i just cant find the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need create new Bills if `id` is empty because your id is primary key and not able empty value.
when you pass empty value to firstOrCreate will try create new Bills but sql will not able this because id is primary key

```
if(empty($request->bill_id)){
  $bill = new Bills();
}else{
 $bill = Bills::findOrFail(['id' => $request->bill_id]);
}
```

Comment: there must be whey to archive my goal with built in functions not writing if else statement.

Comment: no with firstOrNew you can't do this with empty value because id column will not able empty value

Comment: than what is point of using fisrtOrNew in your function, than i could just use find function as it is in Dharmesh Patels answer.

Comment: firstOrNew will work just if you pass value(not empty) ...it's all, yes you can use it

Comment: because your 'id' column  primary key

Answer (score 0):

Following function will help you achieve what you are looking for

```
public function saveBill(Request $request)
{   
    if($request->get('bill_id','') === '') {
        $bill = new Bills();
    } else {
        $bill = Bills::find($request->bill_id);
    }
    $bill->client_id = $request->client_id;
    ...
    $bill->save();
    return redirect('admin/clients/'.$request->client_id);
}
```

Comment: its more like workaround not solution to my question, sorry

I want to use firstOrCreate or firstOrNew  functions to archive this.